# Data Visualization: Plotting friendship relations

Tags: data-visualization

I guess those who have worked in communities and social networks might have some experience in this.

I am trying to plot a graph of all the friendships that exists on my site and in doing so identify clusters of strongly interconnected users.

Does anyone have any experience in doing something like this? Also, does SQL Server 2008 BI have tools that allows for this type of modelling?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to visualize data or get list of interconnected users?

Comment: i want to visualise the list of interconnected users

Comment: You opened a bounty ... tell us what you are not happy with regarding the existing solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Programming Collective Intelligence's chapter 5](http://books.google.com/books?id=fEsZ3Ey-Hq4C&lpg=PP1&dq=programming%20collective%20intelligence&pg=PT136#v=onepage&q=&f=false) is dedicated to optimization and network visualization. [Using the modules available here and the snippet below](http://blog.kiwitobes.com/?p=44), I could make the following image:

```
>>> import optimization
>>> import socialnetwork
>>> sol = optimization.annealingoptimize(socialnetwork.domain, socialnetwork.crosscount, step=50, cool=0.99)
>>> socialnetwork.drawnetwork(sol)
```

[image: chart]

The advantages of this approach is that you can easily change the cost function, use different optimization algorithms, or use another library to view the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `neato` from the [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) command line tool suite. AS input it takes a so called `.dot` file. The format is straight forward you should just be able to iterate over all friendship relations in your system and write them into the file.

Answer (score 3):

For inspiration, take a look at [these social graphs](http://www.visualcomplexity.com/vc/index.cfm?domain=Social%20Networks) from "Visual Complexity" collection.

Many visualizations have explanatory papers and articles mentioning graphing tools, libraries and algorithms used to obtain the images.

Examples from "Social Networks" category:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your graph will be probably reasonably large, so GraphViz is a poor choice. It does a nice job for tiny graphs, but not for huge ones. I'd recommend that you try [aiSee](http://www.aisee.com/) instead (here are some [example graphs](http://www.aisee.com/graph_of_the_month/social.htm)). It requires graphs to be specified in a simple human-readable format called [GDL](http://www.aisee.com/gdl/nutshell/).

[image: Sample social network]
<sub>(source: [aisee.com](http://www.aisee.com/graph_of_the_month/social1.gif))</sub>

---

[Sample social network http://www.aisee.com/graph_of_the_month/pubmed5.gif](http://www.aisee.com/graph_of_the_month/pubmed5.gif)

---

[image: Sample social network]
<sub>(source: [aisee.com](http://www.aisee.com/graph_of_the_month/gnumap.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

For visualization, have a look at the [Javascript Infovis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at the [Girvan-Newman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girvan%E2%80%93Newman_algorithm) algorithm, the output of which gives you an idea of community structure in the form of a dendrogram.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Mark Shepherd's [SpringGraph](http://mark-shepherd.com/blog/springgraph-flex-component/) which is a neat and sexy way of showing big graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [the prefuse visualization toolkit](http://prefuse.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Wikipedia -- Social Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_network) which does talk about social network analysis and graphing relations between users. I think the basic idea is you use a graph to map all the relations and then the more shared relations there are, the higher the interconnected relationships.